# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid with SQLite3::SQLException: no such column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

I'm trying to filter my model by the value an associated model. (I'm trying to filter my variants by store, which is an association of product.

```
class Variant < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :product

def self.by_store_id(store_id)
    where(:product => {:store_id => store_id})
end

### 
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :store

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :products
```

Every time I try this, I get this error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column:
>   product.store_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "variant_skus" INNER JOIN
>   "products" ON "products"."id" = "variant_skus"."product_id" WHERE
>   "product"."store_id" = ?)

Why am I getting this error? Store_id is definitely a column on my product table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is defined, but as it is called `products`, it won't be able to find your column with a `product` prefix. You can use `where('products.store_id = ?', store_id)` in your method.

Comment: This throws the same error. `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: product.store_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "variant_skus" INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = "variant_skus"."product_id" WHERE "product"."store_id" = ?):`

Comment: Woops. Put this in the wrong method. This solved my problem! Thanks a lot!!